# Calc 3 : "Find the surface area of the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2= r^2$ where $2r/3<z$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spheres

Ive been struggling with this problem. I understand that as a surface integral problem I need to parameterize in terms of spherical coordinates. What I don't know is how does $2r/3<z$ affect the bounds and how I am supposed to integrate this. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcom e to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Comment: As for the $2r/3\lt z$ part, it just means that you only need to find the surface area of the part of the sphere that contains points whose $z$-coordinates are greater than two-thirds of the radius. For example, if you had a sphere of radius $1$ and sliced it with the plane $z=2/3$, you would only need to find the surface area of the part of the sphere above that plane.

Comment: You are trying to find the area of the spherical cap above the plane $z=2r/3$.  That's not going to affect $r,$ obviously, and $\theta$ will still go from $0$ to $2\pi$, but obviously $\phi$ will be restricted.  Draw a picture (you can take a cross-section so a two-dimensional picture will suffice) and determine the limits on $\phi.$

Comment: @ColinHogendorn Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

We can use spherical coordinates with

- $x=r\sin \phi \cos \theta$
- $y=r\sin \phi \sin \theta$
- $z=r\cos \phi$

with

- $dS=r^2\sin \phi \,d\phi\,d\theta$

where

- $r$ is constant
- $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$
- $\phi \in (0,\phi_0)$ with $\phi_0=\arccos\left(\frac23 \right)$

therefore

$$S=\int_0^{2\pi} \, d\theta \int_0^{\phi_0} r^2\sin \phi \,d\phi=2\pi r^2\left[-\cos \phi\right]_0^{\phi_0}=-\frac{4}3\pi r^2+2\pi r^2=\frac23 \pi r^2$$

As an alternative and as a check recall taht the area of a [**spherical sector**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector) is given by

- $S=2\pi r h\quad h=r-\frac23 r=\frac13 r\implies S=\frac23 \pi r^2$

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a lot!

Comment: @gimusi Slight nitpick – it should be $z = r \cos \phi$.

Comment: @TobyMak Thanks I fix! Bye

Comment: hey @gimusi how did you find dS? is that what you get from taking the cross product of the partial derivatives?

Comment: Refer to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: I’ve used directly spherical coordinates but we ca also proceed by a different parametrization. Are you interested in se different approach.